# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "gerade", "nur" und "bloß"?

Tags: difference, usage, particle

Ich spreche Englisch als Muttersprache, und einige der Modalpartikeln verstehe ich gar nicht. Gibt es noch mehr, die "just" auf Englisch bedeuten? Was ist der Unterschied zwischen all diesen Varianten?

Beispiele, wie sich ein Satz ändert, wenn diese Wörter eingesetzt werden, würden mir helfen.

Comment: isn't this rather due to the ambiguity of "just". It's no word with exact meaning and often used in phrases like "Just in time", "Just do it" http://www.linguee.de/search?tool=opensearch&query=just Maybe it would be more enlightening to ask when to use just/only/now in English ;) if there are any clear rules of thumb... In most cases "just" can probably be replaced by another more exact word, if you look up the lingue results. Deriving the meaning of a adverb by context seems more common in English, German seems more exact here

Comment: @Hauser I don't want to know what they translate to in English. I want to know exactly how these specific words should be used in German, and if there are any other words similar in meaning that I missed that also have nuances of difference.

Comment: Üblicher Kommentar: Was sagt denn Dein Wörterbuch? Welche Fragen sind danach noch offen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"gerade" hat mehrere Bedeutungen, die nicht alle mit "just" übersetzt werden können. Ich beschränke mich hier auf das "just"-Äquivalent.

- "[nur](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nur_denn_doch)" kann auch mit "only" übersetzt werden:

  > Ich habe nur 5 Euro.
  >   Ich habe bloß 5 Euro. ("[bloß](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/blosz_nur)" wird umgangssprachlich synonym zu "nur" verwendet)
  >   Ich habe gerade mal 5 Euro. (für "gerade mal" bitte Thomas' Kommentar beachten)
  >   I only have 5 Euros.
  >   I just have 5 Euros.
- "[bloß](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/blosz_doch)" wird zur Verstärkung einer Aussage verwendet:

  > Geh mir bloß aus dem Weg! (Dies ist eine Drohung)
  >   Better get out of my way (or something bad will happen)!

Im Gegensatz zu dem oben Gesagten ist "bloß" hier *kein* umgangssprachliches Synonym für "nur":

> Geh mir nur aus dem Weg. (Dies impliziert keine Drohung wie oben. "bloß" ist im obigen Satz verstärkend gebraucht, "nur" wirkt hier abmildernd.)
>   (Would you) just get out of my way

- "gerade" im Sinne von "momentan", "soeben", "in diesem Augenblick"

> Er verlässt gerade das Gebäude.
>   He is just leaving the building.
>   
>   Ja, es gibt noch mehrere Wörter, die "[just](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=just)" bedeuten:
>
> angemessen, ausgerechnet, billig, eben, einfach, genau, gerade, gerade noch, gerecht, halt, nur, soeben, wahr

Comment: Ich nehme 'Ich habe gerade mal 5 Euro' und 'Ich habe gerade 5 Euro' als deutlich voneinander verschieden wahr und würde die Klammern weglassen. 'Ich habe gerade 5 Euro' hat für mich eher die Konnotation 'Wir brauchen 5 Euro, und guck mal, ich habe gerade so viel dabei und es reicht'. 'Ich habe gerade mal 5 Euro' erwarte ich eher in einem Zusammenhang, wo es nicht reicht: 'das Kino kostet 20 Euro, ich habe gerade mal 5 dabei') . Aber das kann regional vielleicht anders sein.

Comment: Danke @Thomas. Ich hatte mir schon überlegt, wie ich das mit dem "mal" am besten erkläre. Das hast Du jetzt gemacht :)

Comment: `"gerade" im Sinne von "momentan", "soeben", "in diesem Augenblick"` --> Hier ist *gerade* kein Partikel, sondern ein Adverb, welches die Satzaussage modifiziert. "Wann verlässt er das Gebäude? - Gerade [=In diesem Moment]." Das Wörtchen fügt hier keine Betonung oder Abschwächung hinzu, was aber die Bedingung wäre, um eine Partikel zu sein.

Answer (score 0):

Genau genommen ist es ziemlich schwierig, diese zu vergleichen. Sie werden in teils unterschiedlichster Weise verwendet und können daher auch mit anderen Worten als *just* übersetzt werden.

Wie dem auch sei. Ihre Gemeinsamkeit ist, dass sie dazu verwendet werden können, eine Betonung auf das zu legen, was du grad sagst. Häufig kann man diese mit **ausgerechnet** ersetzen. In den folgenden Beispielen kannst du alle vier Partikeln (*bloß*, *nur*, *gerade*, *ausgerechnet*) verwenden, aber die Position innerhalb des Satzes ist entscheidend. Du kannst sie also nicht ganz beliebig gegeneinander austauschen.

> Warum passiert das *gerade* [oder *ausgerechnet*] mir?
> Warum *bloß* [oder *nur*] muss ich immer dran glauben?

Es ist fast unmöglich zu sagen, wann welches Wort denn nun verwendet wird. Es ist eher ein Sprachgefühl, das darüber entscheidet, wann welches Wort passt. Man muss hier auch bedenken, dass man auch grundsätzlich die Bedeutung ändern kann.

> Warum passiert das *nur* mir?

In dem Beispiel wird betont, dass man der Einzige ist, dem das passiert, was im vorherigen Beispiel nicht die Aussage des Satzes ist.

Man kann also nicht nach Belieben die Wörter austauschen. Im folgenden Satz, der üblicherweise mit aggressiver Stimme gesagt wird und quasi aussagt, dass der andere einen nicht belästigen soll, werden gängigerweise *bloß* und *nur* verwendet. *Gerade* ist hier absolut fehl am Platz.

> Lass mich bloß in Ruhe!

Naja, zugegeben, in Kombination mit *mal* kannst du sowohl *gerade* als auch *eben* in dem Satz wohl verwendet, aber auch hier änderst du die Satzaussage signifikant. Das vorhin von mir erwähnte *ausgerechnet* funktioniert hier aber in keinster Weise.

> Lass mich *gerade mal* [oder *mal eben*] in Ruhe.

Hier würdest du damit ausdrücken, dass du gerade sehr beschäftigt bist oder dich auf etwas konzentrieren musst und nicht gestört werden möchtest.

Wie auch immer, da es fast unmöglich ist, alle Unterschiede niederzuschreiben, ist es doch notwendig, mit der Zeit dann doch ein Sprachgefühl zu entwickeln und sich nicht auf Definitionen zu verlassen.

In Hinsicht auf deine Frage, welche Wörter die Bedeutung von *just* treffen, musst du natürlich auch bedenken, dass *just* viele Definitionen hat. Hier sind noch einige weitere Partikeln, aber die Liste ist mit Sicherheit noch zu vervollständigen.

> What did you just say? – Was hast du auch **gleich** gesagt?
>
> I was just going to phone you. – Ich wollte dich **eben** anrufen.
>
> That's just impossible – Das ist **einfach** unmöglich.
>
> How does it just happen? – Wie ist das **eigentlich** [oder **überhaupt**, oder **denn**] passiert?